# Android pay integration

Tags: android, in-app-billing, android-pay

I want to integrate Android pay integration in my application, I got the source code from this repo: https://github.com/android-pay/androidpay-quickstart

My problem was:

```
<resources>
  <string name="public_key">BO39Rh43UGXMQy5PAWWe7UGWd2a9YRjNLPEEVe+zWIbdIgALcDcnYCuHbmrrzl
7h8FZjl6RCzoi5/cDrqXNRVSo=</string>

<string name="stripe_publishable_key">REPLACE_ME</string>
<string name="stripe_version">REPLACE_ME</string>
</resources>
```

Where can I get `stripe_publishable_key` and `stripe_version` for testing mode Android Pay?

Answer (score 1):

If you check the source code, those two strings are [only used in one location](https://github.com/android-pay/androidpay-quickstart/blob/9a88f360bbeaa3b1a471ab183c95fc07d9790132/app/src/main/java/com/google/android/gms/samples/wallet/CheckoutActivity.java#L234):

```
...
if (mUseStripe) {
    // Stripe integration
    maskedWalletRequest = WalletUtil.createStripeMaskedWalletRequest(
            Constants.ITEMS_FOR_SALE[mItemId],
            getString(R.string.stripe_publishable_key),
            getString(R.string.stripe_version));
} else {
    ...
```

In other words, they are only relevant if [Stripe](https://stripe.com/) is your payment processor. The meaning of them is explained in the [Stripe documentation](https://stripe.com/docs/dashboard#api-keys):

> **Publishable** API keys are meant solely to identify your account with
>   Stripe, they aren't secret. In other words, they can safely be
>   published in places like your Stripe.js JavaScript code, or in an
>   Android or iPhone app. Publishable keys only have the power to create
>   tokens.
>
> **Secret** API keys should be kept confidential and only stored on your
>   own servers. Your account's secret API key can perform any API request
>   to Stripe without restriction.